# How to compute only a subset of cells in getValuesFocal?

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to compute focal windows on a raster, but i only want to compute the focal window for certain cells (black cells in the picture below). I know, I could compute the focal window for all cells and filter the output afterwards (see example below). But to reduce computational time, is there a way to mask the cells that are computed (e.g with a second raster)?

Example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20, xmn=0, xmx=20, ymn=0, ymx=20)
r[]<-c(1:400)
r.compute.focal<-raster(ncol=20, nrow=20, xmn=0, xmx=20, ymn=0, ymx=20) # raster for which focal window shall be calculated
r.compute.focal[sample(r[],5)]<-1
plot(r)
plot(r.compute.focal,add=T,col="black",legend=F)
```

[image: black cells indicate cells for which the focal window shall be computet]

```
#focal computation
normal.output<-getValuesFocal(r,ngb=5) 

###filtered (desired) output####
normal.output[which(!is.na(r.compute.focal[])),]
```

Comment: Have you had a look yet at `focal(..., NAonly=TRUE)`?

Comment: Unfortunately the NAonly argument is not an option, because i do not want to lose the value of the focal windows' central cell. Also it seems, that even with the NAonly argument all focal windows are computed. At least getValuesFocal behaves that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `adjacent` function for this:

```
# example data
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20, xmn=0, xmx=20, ymn=0, ymx=20)
r[] <- 1:400
set.seed(0)
cells <- sample(r[], 5)

# create 5 x 5 neighborhood matrix for use with adjacent
m <- matrix(1, 5, 5)
# central cell in matrix
m[3,3] <- 0
# find adjacent cells
a <- adjacent(r, cells, m)
# add the focal cells
a <- rbind(a, cbind(cells, cells))

#extract values
b <- extract(r, a[,2])

x <- cbind(a, value=b)

# first column is the focal cell, third column the values
head(x)
#     from  to value
#[1,]  359 317   317
#[2,]  359 337   337
#[3,]  359 357   357
#[4,]  359 377   377
#[5,]  359 397   397
#[6,]  359 318   318

tapply(x[,3], x[,1], mean)
#  106   149   228   359   360 
# 106.0 149.0 228.0 358.5 359.0
```